# PARSE json string to json array (from GET)

Tags: php, json

i'm tring to parse url's json string to an json array.

**ISSUE:** json_decode = empty

**QUESTION:** Does anyone see what am i doing wrong?

**MY STEPS:**

**tests from browser:**

```
.....send.php?{"contactName":"name1"},{"contactName":"name2"}
```

**my php code:**

```
1. $url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
2. $urlStringDecoded = urldecode($url);
```

**echo urlStringDecoded result ok:**

```
{"contactName":"name1"},{"contactName":"name2"}

3. $json = json_decode($urlStringDecoded, true);
```

**RESULT EMPTY**

```
echo("$json");
```

Comment: What's the name of that JSON query string property??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your `JSON` is invalid. Wrap your current string within `[` `]` Brackets.

Eg.

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
//echo $url;
$urlStringDecoded = urldecode($url);
echo $urlStringDecoded;
$json = json_decode("[".$urlStringDecoded."]", true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: @OfirMalachi If it's helped, You can Mark answer as Accepted. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to convert json string to json, you should provide right format. From you example it looks like you are passing , comma separated  json objects whereas it should be an array. Add [] around your string and then try, in other words make it an array.